# Where are jupyter nbextension settings saved, physically? And where are changes to jupyter notebook keyboard shortcuts saved, physically?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to sync my settings for jupyter notebooks across systems with a `dotfiles` Github repo, but I'm not sure where they are stored. Couldn't find the solution anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out myself. Turns out you can find out by entering

```
jupyter nbextensions list
```

and at the top there should be a line that looks like `config dir:/Users/<user>/.jupyter/nbconfig`.

The settings for your changed key mappings and your `nbextension` plugins are all contained in the json file `nbconfig/notebook.json`. Just sync this across systems and your settings will go with you!